# bootstrap-flask проблема с bootstrap Undefined

Tags: python, python-3.x, bootstrap, flask

Тут такая проблема возникла, решил в своем проекте переехать с flask-bootstrap на bootstrap-flask, и следуя гайду: https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate.html вроде все правильно сделал, но не взлетает, ругаясь, на `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'bootstrap' is undefined`. Не понимаю вообще сути проблемы:
Листинг base.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

            {% block styles %}
            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                {{ bootstrap.load_css() }}
            {% endblock %}
            {% block title %}
                {{title}}
            {% endblock %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    {% block navbar %}


    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">HostBill</a>
            </div>
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated%}
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">                
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                   
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">
                            <img src="http://stat.iteam.net.ru/ustats/img/logout2.svg" role="img" />                                Выход {{current_user.login}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>              
            
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
        <!-- Your page content -->
        {% block app_content %}
            <div class="container">

                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
                    {% if messages %}
                        {% for message in messages %}
                            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{{ message }}</div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}        

        {% block scripts %}
            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            {{ bootstrap.load_js() }}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Листинг **init**.py:

```
    from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
    from flask import Flask, session
    from config import Config
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_migrate import Migrate
    from flask_login import LoginManager
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData
    from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base  
    import os
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename    
    app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
    login = LoginManager()
    login.init_app(app)
    login.login_view = 'login'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)    
    from app import views, models
```

Ругается на этот участок кода:

```
{% block styles %}
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  {{ bootstrap.load_css() }}
{% endblock %}
```

UPD: помог способ импортирования boostrap'а напрямую с ресурсов:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Но мой NavBar стал неадекватно себя вести почему то:
[image: Покошенный navbar]

Да класс, аккордеончик заработал, но перестал работать NavBar как на скрине выше

Comment: А зачем нужен flask_bootstrap если можно самостоятельно добавить бутстрап в проект? :) Типа такого: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5a780831079c69cd2351a2249d6c8397c6f27a57/flask__webservers/bootstrap_4__examples/clickable_table/templates/index.html#L8 :)

Comment: хочу что б это все было на уровне джинджи и питона

Comment: когда я делал по твоему способу, у меня не хотел работать некоторые вещи типа аккордеона и карточек

Comment: Мб, версии бутстрапа напутали? Есть вот аккодион (версия 5) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/ , а если его аналог (версия 4): https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/components/collapse/ . Делал flask с bootstrap 4.5 с такой фигней: https://github.com/gil9red/lenta_of_played_games/blob/f46b75ce89399fde1911721e8380d3506ff6a7b8/templates/index.html#L112

Comment: ну а как проверить какой версии бутстрап фляжковский именно

Comment: Посмотреть описание библиотеки flask_bootstrap, мб в его репозитории описано, либо дать ему сгенерировать страницу и посмотреть какие зависимости к бутстрапу на странице (думаю или в пути будет версия или внутри файлов бутстрапа)

Comment: Не помог способ с ручным подключением ресурсов, не видит их мой шаблон

Comment: Думаю, лучше убрать импорт `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js`, раз уже импортируете 5 версию вместе с ее css

Comment: убрал, но NavBar все еще болеет

Comment: Смотрите что у вас не так: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: немного не пойму, можно носом тыкнуть?

Comment: У вас `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">` там `<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">`. Там нет `navbar-default`, скорее всего, это в старой версии бутстрапа было

Comment: переделал, но все равно плохо ему

Comment: Возможно, еще какие-то классы/теги используете, что были в старой версии

Comment: собственно все решилось по вашему методу: т.е перебрал все классы и заменил старые

Comment: Хорошо, что разрешилось :) Оформите, пожалуйста, ответ с описанием решения, чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа :)

Comment: я не знаю как правильно оформить и куда нажать что бы закрыть вопрос, я здесь новичок(

Comment: Внизу страницы есть кнопка "Ответить на собственный ответ", вот вы в нем напишите как решили проблему, если будет, возможно, с примерами или кодом. После, дня, по-моему, через 3 примите его :)

Answer (score 1):

В общем решение следующее:
Подключаем вручную бутстрап

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">   

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

И затем проходимся по всему коду меняя классы, так как некоторые классы 5 и 4 версии изменены